Tone.Transport.clear(eventID) is not removing the corresponding audio from the timeline
I'm using ToneJS to create an AudioPlayback component in React. Each audio snippet I want to play is loaded into a buffer in the beginning. When I want to schedule audio at a time, I create a new player using an existing buffer, schedule the player using Tone.Transport.schedule(), and save the eventID into a React state. Sometimes I want to update an event (ex: changing the start time but using the same audio buffer), so I call Tone.Transport.clear(eventID) then schedule the audio with a new player at the new start time. However, when I listen to the audio playback, the old audio is still there such that it plays both at the old and the new times.
Tone.Transport.cancel() seems to work fine in removing all events from the audio timeline, but I don't want to clear and reschedule every event every time I want to change a single event. Why doesn't Tone.Transport.clear() behave as expected?
Here is the code for the component:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { set } from 'react-hook-form';
import * as Tone from 'tone';

interface Props {
    sectionStarts: Map<string, number>; // sectionId -> start time in beats
    projectBpm: number;
    audioURIs: Map<string, Array<string>>; // sectionId -> array of audio file paths for the section
    sectionHasUpdated: Map<string, boolean>; // sectionId -> whether need to updateScheduledEvent for section
    setSectionHasUpdated: (sectionHasUpdated: Map<string, boolean>) => void;
}

function AudioPlayback({ sectionStarts, projectBpm, audioURIs, sectionHasUpdated, setSectionHasUpdated }: Props) {
    const [scheduledEventIDs, setScheduledEventIDs] = useState<Map<string, number>>(new Map()); // map of key (sectionID-index) to eventID
    const [audioContextLoaded, setAudioContextLoaded] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const allBuffers = new Tone.Buffers();

    const loadBuffer = async (key: string, path: string) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const buffer = new Tone.Buffer(path, () => {
                allBuffers.add(key, buffer);
                resolve(buffer);
            }, (error) => {
                console.error(`Failed to load buffer at ${path}:`, error);
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    };

    const ensureBufferLoaded = async (key: string, path: string) => {
        if (!allBuffers.has(key)) {
            await loadBuffer(key, path);
            console.log("Buffer loaded for:", key)
        }
    };

    const scheduleAudioFile = (key: string, audioFilePath: string, startTime: number) => { // startTime in beats
        ensureBufferLoaded(key, audioFilePath).then(() => {
            const player = new Tone.Player(allBuffers.get(key)).toDestination();

            const eventId = Tone.Transport.schedule(time => {
                player.start(time);
            }, `0:${startTime}:0`);

            scheduledEventIDs.set(key, eventId);
            console.log("Event scheduled for:", key);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error("Error scheduling audio file:", error);
        });

    }

    const cancelScheduledEvent = (key: string) => {
        const eventId = scheduledEventIDs.get(key);
        if (eventId !== undefined) {
            Tone.Transport.clear(eventId);
            scheduledEventIDs.delete(key); // Remove the key and ID from the map

        }
        else {
            console.error("Failed to cancel scheduled event for key:", key)
        }
    }

    const updateScheduledEvent = (key: string, newAudioFilePath: string, newStartTime: number) => {
        Tone.Transport.stop();
        Tone.Transport.position = 0;

        cancelScheduledEvent(key);
        scheduleAudioFile(key, newAudioFilePath, newStartTime);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        sectionHasUpdated.forEach((hasUpdated, sectionId) => {
            if (hasUpdated) {
                const audioURIsForSection = audioURIs.get(sectionId);
                if (audioURIsForSection !== undefined) {
                    const sectionStartTime = sectionStarts.get(sectionId);
                    if (sectionStartTime !== undefined) {
                        audioURIsForSection.forEach((audioURI, index) => {
                            const key = sectionId + "-" + index;
                            updateScheduledEvent(key, audioURI, sectionStartTime + index * 4);
                        });
                        setSectionHasUpdated(new Map(sectionHasUpdated.set(sectionId, false)));
                    }
                }

            }
        })

    }, [sectionHasUpdated])

    const startTone = async () => {
        await Tone.start();
        Tone.Transport.bpm.value = projectBpm;
        setAudioContextLoaded(true);
    }

    const playButton = () => {
        return (
            <button disabled={!audioContextLoaded} onClick={() => {
                Tone.Transport.start()
                setIsPlaying(true)
            }}>Play</button>
        )
    }

    const pauseButton = () => {
        return (
            <button disabled={!audioContextLoaded} onClick={() => {
                Tone.Transport.pause()
                setIsPlaying(false)
            }}>Pause</button>
        )
    }

    const stopButton = () => {
        return (
            <button disabled={!audioContextLoaded} onClick={() => {
                Tone.Transport.stop()
                setIsPlaying(false)
            }}>Stop</button>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={startTone}>Create Audio Context</button>
            {isPlaying ? pauseButton() : playButton()}
            {stopButton()}
        </div >
    )
}

export default AudioPlayback;

